# linq where contains ALL items in list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of filters and I want to use it to query a table where the returned items contain ALL of the values not just 1.

For example I have a label/tag system. I want to return records that have the tag 'sport' AND 'football' in them. However 'sport' and 'football' are stored in a list and could be any number of other tags that the user supplies.

I'm using entity framework. I have a Tags, Teams, TeamTags table. My current query is as such:

```
string _tags = "sport,football";
List<string> tags = _tags.Split(',').ToList();

var teams = (from t in db.Tags where tags.Contains(t.TagName) select t.Teams).FirstOrDefault().Select(i => i.TeamNames).ToList()
```

But this will return all teams that have the 'sport' tag not those that are labeled as 'sports' AND 'football' only.

If you imagine typing the 'sport' tag first you'd get a list of teams from all sports. Then you add the 'football' tag that list would be filtered even more to just the football teams. So my code above basically does an OR in the where. I want the ability to do an AND as well.

So example data in the database would be:

Broncos has sport and football tags
Mets has sport and baseball tags

I want the team that has sport AND football tags, not sport OR football tags.

Comment: You're using a relationship from `Tags` to `Teams` in your code. Is there a way to go from `Teams` to their `Tags`?

Comment: Why don't you use `SelectMany` and produce a projection for the `Contains` on those values?

Comment: @Greg because I've never used SelectMany or know what you are talking about when you say 'produce a projection'.

Comment: @JLRishe Yes it's a 2way street.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest giving this a try:

```
var teams = (from team in db.Teams 
             where tags.All(tag => team.Tags.Any(ttag => ttag.TagName == tag))
             select team).ToList();
```

From there, if you want a list of the names, you can do a projection on that (it's hard to entirely grok how your data structures are set up, but something like this):

```
var teamNames = teams.Select(t => t.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: That did it. Now I have to try and understand it :)

Comment: @user441521 You can just read it from the inside out: `team.Tags.Any(ttag => ttag.TagName == tag)` will be true if _any_ of the team's tags have the value `tag`. `tags.All(tag => (that bit I just explained)` will be true if that's true for _all_ of the items in `tags`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string _tags = "sport,football";
List<string> tags = _tags.Split(',').ToList();

var teams = (from t in db.Tags where tags.All(x=> x.Contains(t.TagName)) select t.Teams).FirstOrDefault().Select(i => i.TeamNames).ToList();
```

This should help get you the desired result

Comment: First I think you meant `tags.All(x => t.TagName.Contains(x))`.  Otherwise you are saying "sport" and "football" both contain a substring equal to `TagName`.  Second that fix assumes that `TagName` is something like "sport, football", but I believe there are separate entries in the Tags table for sports and football that link to one or many teams.

Comment: you may have some issues when this gets converted into sql (since you're using EF). you may run into a N+1 issue. Just be wary. How many teams and tags you have can make a big difference. If everything is in memory and you have a lot of tags you're searching on (the `tags` variable), it may be worth converting it from List<string> to HashSet<string> (cut off is probably around 5 tags).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kinds lame, but to get EF core working, and return only elements where a collection suppose to contain all elements I had to do something like this:

```
            // var query = context....;

            foreach (var tag in tags)
            {
                query = query.Where(p => p.TagList.Any(t => t == tag));
            }

            return query;
```